# Correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, likert

Is it necessary to convert the scores of a 5-item Likert scale questionnaire and the scores of a reading comprehension test to z-scores in order to estimate the correlation coefficient (Since their scales are much different)?

Comment: What is your purpose in computing a correlation coefficient here ? Is it just exploratory or something else ?

Comment: The most commonly used tests for significance of correlation assume normal data. Not that 'standardization' (whatever that may mean to you) will necessarily guarantee normal data, but it may help.

Comment: If you are planning a linear transformation, then no, as you get the same correlation whatever the scales of the original data

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the z-scores of items on a Likert scale are not meaningful because the latter is an ordinal measurement scale.  Nevertheless, the usual practice when looking at correlation of ordinarl variable is to use the [Spearman correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient), which is equivalent to the Pearson correlation of the ranks of the variables.  This is invariant to linear transformations of the ranks of the variables, so it really doesn't matter if you use the values 1-5 for your scales or the z-scores of the values.